# Sending an anonymous email to my own address

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient, networkcredentials

I want to send an anonymous email to my own gmail/hotmail/yahoo/any other mail service address (Im not trying to spam or something like that).

Why? I have a .NET application and I want to add a "Send log to the developer" feature (attaching the log) using SmtpClient. The fact is I've read like 30+ pages, and found out, i.e. gmail's smtp client doesn't allow anonymous connections, and many other things.

The idea is to receive a mail message like this:

```
From: logs@myapp.com (non-existent email really)

To: myrealaddress@somedomain.com (this would be my real address which will recieve the logs attachments)

Subject: Issue report nºX (auto-generated)

Body: From a textbox

Attachments: logs attached
```

Is this possible?  If so, how do I achieve it?

Comment: If you're only sending it to yourself, why does it have to be anonymous?

Comment: I've done this in my applications.  The trick is having an email server that will accept your mail for forwarding to it's final destination. And I agree with @GalacticCowboy, why does it have to be sent anonymously?

Comment: Because the .net app is going to be used by many users, and I don't want them to introduce their own credentials and smtp servers and port. This will make them feel unsafe using it.

Comment: @N3HL - right - so use your credentials and smtp server.  Of course, you need to keep your credentials secure.

Comment: @STLDeveloper but the "Sender" would be a non-existent mail, thats my point

Comment: @N3HL - No - it wouldn't.  It could (probably should) be an account you setup specifically to send these messages to you.

Comment: @STLDeveloper, thats the point, the idea is to send a mail from a non-existent mail to my real mail. The "sender" mail has no smtp server, no port, nothing at all. So you are suggesting the best solution is to have 2 separate email addresses (one to send the log and the other one to recieve it) or just use one mail as "sender"/"reciever"

Comment: @N3HL, I tried moving this message to chat, so that we could discuss the solution to your issue, but as you have a reputation of 6, that is not enough to chat.  The bottom line is that in order to send email via SMTP, you must have an SMTP server to connect to.  That will require an email account (address) and password.  The email address you're sending to is immaterial.  I've done the same thing in my own applications.  The risky part is that you have to find a way to hide your credentials so that no one else can lift them.  I do this via encryption.

Comment: @STLDeveloper I don't want to obfuscate the code because of just a little thing like this. I understand what you are saying.

The "sender" has to be a valid email, with a valid SMTP server that authenticates it. Then I can send mails to non-existent addresses. But what im saying is exactly the opposite. I want to send from i.e. logs@frommyapp.com to my real address. Of course the "sender" in this case will have no password, no credentials at all, that's why I titled "anonymous emails".

Comment: @N3HL - I'm not suggesting that you send email to non-existent email addresses - that wouldn't make much sense.  I understand that you want to send the mail as though it were from some fictional address.  Please see my answer below.  I think you take a close look at it you will see what I'm talking about.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't reliably achieve this.  You can get it to work in some cases, but not all.

Most email servers these days have spam filters and rules for checking on emails, and in most cases an empty 'From' address will result in special treatment.  Sometimes that just means a slightly higher spam score from the receiving mail server, but in some cases an empty 'From' address will result in your email being silently dropped in the bit bucket.  You have no control over this, and neither will your users.  It's all down to how the receiving mail server is configured.

The simplest option is generally to allow the user to configure a from address and SMTP server.  Some servers will require login to send messages, so you have to consider that.  Many ISP mail servers (and most internal workplace mail servers) don't require login if the connection is coming from an address owned by the ISP (or workplace) and the email address is one that is registered as belonging there.  Some ISPs - and this number is apparently growing - require SMTP login to send mail regardless.

Another option is to set up a source domain, configure the SPF record for the domain to allow email from any IP address, and use a standard 'From' address in that domain.  The downside to this is that once someone discovers that you've opened up a domain that way they'll start using it to send spam and you'll get shut down.

There are many other options that have their own problems.  One of the problems is that they generally cost money - some setup costs, most options also with ongoing costs - or open you up to liabilities of some sort.

Give your users the choice.  Let them try various options and see what works for them: no 'From' address, user-defined 'From' address (same as 'To' address is a good first try), partial SMTP login, full SMTP login, etc.  If they don't trust your code enough to put their passwords in, let them create a throw-away account on gmail or something to run the messages through.